# Is it possible to listen to a custom prototype event from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

If I fire a custom event in prototype.js can I listen for that event in jquery?

I tried this but it doesn't work

```js
$.noConflict();

$('target').observe('custom:event', function(){
  console.log("prototype method");
});

jQuery("#target").on("custom:event",function(){
  console.log("jquery method");
});

$('target').fire('custom:event');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you don't use the custom event's name. You would set an event listener for the event `dataavailable`, as that is what Prototype sets any custom events to go through.

> https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/560bb59414fc9343ce85429b91b1e1b82fdc6812/src/prototype/dom/event.js#L635
>
> ```
> if (isCustomEvent(eventName))
>   observeCustomEvent(element, eventName, responder);
> else
>   observeStandardEvent(element, eventName, responder);
> ```
>
> https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/560bb59414fc9343ce85429b91b1e1b82fdc6812/src/prototype/dom/event.js#L654
>
> ```
>  function observeCustomEvent(element, eventName, responder) {
>     if (element.addEventListener) {
>       element.addEventListener('dataavailable', responder, false);
>     } else {
>       // We observe two IE-proprietarty events: one for custom events that
>       // bubble and one for custom events that do not bubble.
>       element.attachEvent('ondataavailable', responder);
>       element.attachEvent('onlosecapture',   responder);
>     }
>   }
> ```

So to listen for a Prototype event do something like:

```
jQuery("#target").on("dataavailable",function(e){
  if(e.originalEvent.eventName == "custom:event"){
    doWhatever();
  }
  //Or even do a trigger through jQuery by passing the 
  //event target and event name
  //this will allow you to just set events like you were
  //with jQuery and not need a bunch of if statements
  jQuery(e.target).trigger(e.originalEvent.eventName);
});
```

Demo

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
var protoTarget = $('target');
var jQueryTarget = jQuery('#target');

protoTarget.observe('custom:event', function(e){
  protoTarget.append('Prototype callback');
});

jQuery(document).on("dataavailable",function(e){
  jQuery(e.target).trigger(e.originalEvent.eventName);
});

jQueryTarget.on("custom:event",function(){
  jQueryTarget.append("<br>jQuery callback");
});

$('target').fire('custom:event');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>
```